# How to make a HTTP GET with custom certificate with Spring Boot / javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl

One of my providers gave me a WSDL file to make a SOAP request to his server, with a SSL Cert.

With SOAP UI, I can do this request, so I am sure the service works, and certificate is OK.

Now, I generated java code from wsimport, and try to run this same request from Spring Boot.

I manage SSL from front-end (K8S / traefik) and not from inside app.

When I go to my prod url, I can see that it is using the certificate, and I when I click to the lock on the left of url, in chrome, I can see "Connection is Secure", and the right info about my cert.

But still, it doesn't work, and when I check logs, I get:

```
2020-02-17 14:05:28.346 ERROR 1 --- [nio-8081-exec-9] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.] with root cause

javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1362) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1337) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:274) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1343) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1304) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:307) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1356) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.consulterMesuresDetaillees(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.sunchain.sge.MainApplication.getMeasures(MainApplication.java:74) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]

2020-02-17 14:07:35.314  INFO 1 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.a.c.w.s.f.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean : Creating Service {http://www.enedis.fr/sge/b2b/services/consultationmesuresdetaillees/v1.0}ConsultationMesuresDetaillees-v1.0 from WSDL: classpath:ConsultationMesuresDetailleesV1.0_v1.2.0/Services/ConsultationMesuresDetaillees/ConsultationMesuresDetaillees-v1.0.wsdl
2020-02-17 14:07:35.445  WARN 1 --- [io-8081-exec-10] o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain      : Interceptor for {http://www.enedis.fr/sge/b2b/services/consultationmesuresdetaillees/v1.0}ConsultationMesuresDetaillees-v1.0#{http://www.enedis.fr/sge/b2b/services/consultationmesuresdetaillees/v1.0}consulterMesuresDetaillees has thrown exception, unwinding now

org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:67) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:530) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:441) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:356) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:314) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:140) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy106.consulterMesuresDetaillees(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.xxx.sge.MainApplication.getMeasures(MainApplication.java:74) ~[classes!/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:190) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:138) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:106) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:888) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:793) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1040) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:943) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) ~[spring-web-5.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/:5.2.0.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:747) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.27.jar!/:9.0.27]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSLHandshakeException invoking https://sge-b2b.enedis.fr/ConsultationMesuresDetaillees/v1.0: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.mapException(HTTPConduit.java:1400) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1384) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:671) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: handshake_failure
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:131) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:307) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:180) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:567) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1362) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1337) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:246) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.setupWrappedStream(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:274) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleHeadersTrustCaching(HTTPConduit.java:1343) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(HTTPConduit.java:1304) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.URLConnectionHTTPConduit$URLConnectionWrappedOutputStream.onFirstWrite(URLConnectionHTTPConduit.java:307) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractWrappedOutputStream.write(AbstractWrappedOutputStream.java:47) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.io.AbstractThresholdOutputStream.write(AbstractThresholdOutputStream.java:69) ~[cxf-core-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1356) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.3.3.jar!/:3.3.3]
    ... 63 common frames omitted
```

I don't understand why isn't it working, and what should I do to make it work. I can share any code if needed.

Comment: I guess the provider gave you a **_client_** certificate. It is what you'll use when you're consuming the operations specified in the `wsdl`. That is what you're using when verifying the service with SOAPUI. If you can see the certificate when browsing your site then that means you're not using it as a client certificate, but as a **_server_** certificate to identify your server. (I'd expect that Chrome warned you that the certificate was not valid when browsing the site and you bypassed that?)

Comment: Yep ! I guess you are right !  So, what should I do ?

Comment: you could put it as an answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just an example, cobbled together from some old code from way back. I no longer have access to a SOAP service that requires mutual TLS and it is not tested in it's current form.

That being said you should be able to use it as a starting point - depending on which libraries you're using. The important thing is to have your SOAP client provide the client certificate your provider gave you while making requests.

```
import org.apache.cxf.configuration.jsse.TLSClientParameters;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;
import org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.KeyStoreException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.util.Optional;

public class CrudeSoapClient {

    private static void initKeyManager(YourSoapServicePort yourSoapServicePort) {
        HTTPConduit httpConduit = (HTTPConduit) ClientProxy.getClient(yourSoapServicePort).getConduit();
        TLSClientParameters tlsClientParameters = Optional.ofNullable(httpConduit.getTlsClientParameters()).orElseGet(TLSClientParameters::new);
        tlsClientParameters.setKeyManagers(getKeyManagerFactory().getKeyManagers());
        httpConduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsClientParameters);
    }

    public static KeyManagerFactory getKeyManagerFactory() {
        KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = null;
        try (InputStream inputStream = CrudeSoapClient.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("yourkeystore.pkcs12")) {
            KeyStore ts = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            ts.load(inputStream, "yourpassword".toCharArray());
            keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            keyManagerFactory.init(ts, "yourpassword".toCharArray());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return keyManagerFactory;
    }
}
```

It could be invoked like so

```
        YourSoapService yourSoapService = new YourSoapServicePort();
        YourSoapServicePort yourSoapServicePort = yourSoapService.getYourSoapServicePort();
        CrudeSoapClient.initKeyManager(yourSoapServicePort);
        YourSoapServiceResponse response = yourSoapServicePort.getOperation(yourRequest);
        //do whatever you need to do with the response
```